# automáticamente al boton "examinar" al entrar a la pagina

Tags: autocompletar, descargar

Cual seria el codigo para que la persona que entre a mi pagina web automáticamente presione por ejemplo el boton "examinar" (para buscar foto y luego subirla) se entiende ? gracias

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y pulsa en [edit] para proveer más detalles a tu pregunta. Sin contexto, es muy difícil ayudar. Además: ¿qué has intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: Hola NkL DJ Chile, que yo sepa, no hay ningún código que haga que una persona oprima un botón, no broma, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver el código de tu aplicación, porfi, edita tu pregunta y agregalo como texto, gracias!!.